# Displaying MySQL Data in PHP in a hidden div

Tags: php, html, css

I have this HTML code for my div:

```
<div id="ticketupdates" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

then within the div i have this PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $sql2="
    SELECT 
    ticket_seq, 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(notes),'<br><br><a href=\"/admin/helpdesk/uploaded-ticket-files/',filename,'\">',filename,'</a>') as displaydata, 
    datetime as timestamp, 
    updatedby, 
    CONCAT('<strong>Time Start: </strong>',timestart,' - <strong>Time End: </strong>',timeend) as timestartend
    from ticket_updates where ticket_seq = '".$result["ticketnumber"]."'

    UNION

    SELECT 
    ticket_seq, 
    CONCAT('<strong>',ticketchange,'</strong><br>' ,description) as displaydata, 
    datetime as timestamp,  
    changed_by as updatedby, 
    blankfield
    from ticket_changes where ticket_seq = '".$result["ticketnumber"]."' 

    ORDER by timestamp ASC ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        $timestartend2 = ($result2["timestartend"] > '') ? '<br><br>'.$result2["timestartend"] : '';

        echo '<tr>
                        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#666666" align="left"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>'.$result2["updatedby"].'</strong></font></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#666666" align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>'.$result2["timestamp"].'</strong></font></td>
                      </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">'.nl2br($result2["displaydata"]).''.$timestartend2.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                  </tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

obviously the div is hidden as its got `display:none` on the style of it but it's still displaying the PHP results.

If i just put some plain text inside the div like this:

```
<div id="ticketupdates" style="display:none;">
hello
</div>
```

it doesn't display. I am doing this as I have a link that expands the `div` to show the content.

Any ideas why it's not working with the PHP Code?

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*`, it's deprecated (use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead). It also looks like you're making SQL-injections really easy, since you embed a result directly into your query string.

Comment: What does your actual rendered HTML look like?

Comment: I do not see any `<table />` element.

Comment: How does your PHP code interact with the 'ticketupdates' div? Are they in the same file? Are you trying to load the output of the PHP script via AJAX? Please clearly indicate the link between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open and close that table that your putting rows and columns too? If you did not open it, you might get some unexpected results.

The name of the ID '#ticketupdates' sounds like this could be loaded by an AJAX request? 
Try hiding it after the request with Javascript, or with jQuery;

```
$('#ticketupdates').hide();
```

And for the open doors; please try to not use *mysql_** functions, and try to seperate the PHP and styling from the HTML (especially from SQL).